# Generate new UITableViewController and show it

Tags: ios, treeview, uitableview

I'm working with tableviews showing a hierarchy data structure. I take the first node and show the sons in the tableview and repeat it until the end of the tree. I'm doing it in this way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([[actualNode getSonAtIndex:0] sonsCount]>0) {
    NSLog(@"New level");
    actualNode = [actualNode getSonAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Service");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Service" sender:NULL];
}
```

It is not the correct way but the problem is that I don't know how many levels has the tree so I can't create them in the Storyboard. The idea is create only one TableView for showing each level but doing it in that way I can't go back to the previous level on the NavBar like I could do if I was working with some controllers in the storyboard and I don't have animations. So, is there any way to do it? something like:

```
MyNextLevel *nextlevel = [MyNextLevel alloc];
[nextlevel setNode: actualNode]
Myactualtableview = nextlevel; (Here the next level is showed in the screen with animations and with the possibility to go back to the previous level)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why I don't like storyboards. It has always been possible to do what you want to do (if I'm understanding it correctly), but storyboards detract from it; they don't have the flexibility of doing things in code, which is what we always had to do back in iOS 3 and iOS 4 anyway.

Anyhow, you want to do something like this:

```
UITableViewController* tvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
```

Your business logic can just pick the class for MyTableViewController. Alternatively, MyTableViewController could be something flexible, where between those two lines you give it some configuration info that causes it to show the right data! (I have to admit, though, that you *could* do that same thing using a storyboard, configuring the table view controller in `performSegue:`.)

Comment: At first thanks for your answer, but I couldn't tried yet: I haven't created a specific NIB file. My class's name is "NextLevelController" and inherits from UITableViewController , how can I know whats the name of the NIB I'm using?

Comment: You don't *have* to use a nib with a UITableViewController; in that case, just supply nil as the nib, and the UITableViewController will make a default table view and hook everything up nicely.

Comment: If you *do* want to use a nib with a UITableViewController, then when you create the UITableViewController subclass in Xcode you should check the checkbox that asks if you want a nib. That way, you'll get the right kind of nib, with the right name, and with the table view and everything hooked up correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote you that because I had already tried with nil but it give me this error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: That's a totally different error. That's because you are calling `dequeue...` but you've never registered the cell class.

Comment: It finally works adding: [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]; in the viewDidLoad. Thanks for all Matt.

Comment: Here's more about registering the cell class (from my book): http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_registering_a_cell_class The reason you didn't have to deal with this before is that it isn't necessary if the table view controller comes from a storyboard.